# How to model "products" in an online store application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, language-agnostic, e-commerce, modeling

I'm building an online store to sell products like "Green Extra-large, T-shirts". I.e., the same shirt can have many sizes / colors, different combination can be sold out, different combination might have different prices, etc.

My question is how I should model these products in my Rails application (or really how to do it in any application).

My current thinking is:

```
Class Product
  has_many :variants, :through => :characteristics
  has_many :characteristics 
end

Class Characteristic
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :variants
end

Class Variant
  has_many :products, :through => :characteristics
  belongs_to :characteristic
end
```

So each product will have one or more characteristics (e.g., "Color", "Size", etc), and each characteristic will then have one or more variants (e.g., "Red", "Blue", etc).

The problem with this method is **where do I store price and inventory?** I.e., a given product's price and inventory are determined by the variants its characteristics take. (Green might be more expensive than red, large might be out of stock, etc).

One thought I had was to give products a "base_price", and let variants modify it, but this seems overly complex (and might not work).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have seen two solutions to this kind of dilemma. The first is to try to use characteristics to define subordinate products to the "main" product. The challenge here is that in addition to your thoughts for far, in most cases the product will evolve with new manufacturers that bring new aspects to the table. For example, one manufacturer may make a cheaper product, but have a different application method for the logo or stitching that may be significant enough to track.

I think that carrying a non significant product number for each product and then attaching the characteristics as attributes works out the best. It is easily searched and extensible.  If a group of products are strongly related, a ProductGroup that the individual products attach to works well.

In tables:

```
            ProductGroup
            --------------------
            ProductGroupID
            ProductGroupName
            ProductGroupDescription

            Product
            --------------------
            ProductID
            ProductGroupID
            QtyOnHand
            BasePrice
            ProductColorID
            ProductSizeID

            ProductColor
            ------------
            ProductColorID
            ProductColorName

            ProductSize
            --------------
            ProductSizeID
            ProductSizeName

            ...more attributes...
```

The advantages here are that you can easily query for specific attributes, attributes are "flexible" in that more can be added (and old ones adjusted: if you started with "Red" but then added another "Red" to the color pool, you can change them to "Maroon" and "Bright Red".

You can control price and inventory are at the detail product level (although more tables may be required to account for *sourcing* costs).

**This all assumes that your characteristics are universally shared.**  If they are not, your characteristic subtable approach can work by creating a join table between characteristics and the product detail tables and populate as needed. This will require more business logic .to ensure each product category gets *all* characteristics necessary. **In this latter case I would use "prototype" products in the base product table (with Qty and Cost of 0) that I would clone the characteristics from and then adjust as each new product is entered.** As you move forward, when a new variation appears, having a "clone this product" function that allows you to just adjust the *differences* from the base product would be valuable.

Finally, as far as managing the inventory and pricing, this is going to happen at the UI layer. Being able to generate queries for related products (product groups) and manage all the pricing for related products will go a long way to making this livable.

Comment: This is sound advice. At the company I work for we have just two tables -- Product and ProductItem -- and color and size wasn't properly normalized out. It makes managing/associating color-specific images an absolute nightmare. This is how I would do it; color and size are first-class concepts....

Comment: ...and we've run into scenarios where "the yellows are made in Thailand but the whites are from China", but since we store that at the Product level we can't model that and end up duplicating the SKU, which causes other problems. Being flexible but providing UI for the common scenarios is +1 advice.

Comment: Thanks Nicholas. This advice comes from being burned too often by assuming that the "easy" characteristics can just be stuffed in the main table. I can easily see that the "Color" table eventually gains more attributes due to sourcing differences. Fool me once...

Answer (score 2):

Just a quick-note. You can always try and take a look at the sourcecode of some other e-commerce products like [Spree](http://spreehq.org/) and [Substruct](http://code.google.com/p/substruct/) they probably already answered that question for you.